# Generate alphanumeric 8-character strings in UNIX shell

Tags: shell, unix

I mean sequentially generate all combinations of 8 alphanumeric characters. Like what you would use for bruteforcing an 8-digit password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this thoroughly, but it should be a start.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

declare -A aa=(
  [0]=1 [1]=2 [2]=3 [3]=4 [4]=5 [5]=6 [6]=7 [7]=8 [8]=9 [9]=A [A]=B [B]=C [C]=D
  [D]=E [E]=F [F]=G [G]=H [H]=I [I]=J [J]=K [K]=L [L]=M [M]=N [N]=O [O]=P [P]=Q
  [Q]=R [R]=S [S]=T [T]=U [U]=V [V]=W [W]=X [X]=Y [Y]=Z [Z]=a [a]=b [b]=c [c]=d
  [d]=e [e]=f [f]=g [g]=h [h]=i [i]=j [j]=k [k]=l [l]=m [m]=n [n]=o [o]=p [p]=q
  [q]=r [r]=s [s]=t [t]=u [u]=v [v]=w [w]=x [x]=y [y]=z [z]=0
)

bb=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

while :
do
  IFS= read ff <<< "${bb[*]}"
  echo $ff
  place=7
  while :
  do
    bb[place]=${aa[${bb[place]}]}
    if [ ${bb[place]} = 0 ]
    then
      (( place-- ))
    else
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that mean that you'd want `218,340,105,584,896` combinations ? ie `62 ** 8` if we agree that you get 1,000 combinations of numerical digits in 3 places ie 10 ** 3 == 1,000.

My math may not be correct though. ://

If that's the case you should consider doing it in Python/Perl